# How can I autopan in Cesium to guarantee a popup will be fully displayed?

Tags: math, 3d, cesiumjs

I have a [sandcastle](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/#c=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).

When the sandcastle comes up, I can press the Show button and my popup appears and is fully contained within the viewer.

[image: initial state image and fully contained]

If I rotate the globe and update the position of the popup by pressing the show button again, the popup may not be fully contained within the viewer.

[image: rotated and not fully contained]

What do I need to change so I can programmatically minimally rotate the globe so the popup will be fully contained?

If I didn't care about a minimal rotation, I could use the camera's [flyTo](https://cesium.com/learn/cesiumjs/ref-doc/Camera.html?classFilter=camera#flyTo) function and center the position within the viewer (press the Center button). The other option would be to figure out how much of the popup was outside of the viewer and adjust the position accordingly. However, this adjustment would lose the idea of the position being the anchor point for the popup.

It can be assumed the popup will be less than half the width and height of the viewer area which will guarantee a minimal rotation will be possible. This is also why the flyTo is guaranteed to work.

Perhaps this functionality already exists within Cesium and there is an alternative I am not aware of...?